# Looking for a laptop to learn game development on the go

Tags: laptop, game-development

So I'm looking for a computer to learn game development on, that should cover the following bases:

- Have either a 15.6 or 17.3" screen (not sure which would be better for me, but no less than 15.6")
- Have a decent GPU (most likely GTX 960m)
- Have a decent CPU (prob. 5th/6th gen intel i7, most I looked at had the 6700HQ)
- Have either 16GB ram or 8GB with the option of upgrading to 16GB
- Have an IPS panel
- either good battery life or some way to charge without a wall socket e.g. USB 3.1 with reversible power.
- not be incredibly expensive (800-1k$)

(I'm willing to compromise on a count or two if it's a better choice overall)

after a lot of searching I actually found a few that covered my bases, except the last one (battery life). since by definition powerful laptops require more power, most of the rigs I looked at didn't have amazing battery time.
knowing this I looked for ones with USB 3.1-C ports thinking I could charge them via power bank.
but after settling on the  ASUS GL552VW/GL752VW, I found out that it does NOT support the PD 2.0 standard meaning it's useless for charging and I would be limited to the lackluster ~4hr battery.

So, that being said- here are some of the laptops I've considered so far:

1. [Dell Inspiron i7559-2512BLK](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834298771&cm_re=dell_i7559-_-34-298-771-_-Product)
2. [ASUS ROG GL752VW-DH71 (17" version)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834232770&cm_re=Asus_gl752vw-_-34-232-770-_-Product)

Any recommendations or general input would be more than welcome!

**P.S. - I know a desktop would be better for my purposes, but that's not a relevant option for me at the moment.**

Comment: What's your target platform? If you are targeting many (older) versions of Android you end up needing gigabytes on your HD. If you are using your laptop for example for graphics editing, music software and games, you will find that you run out of space soon and might need an external HD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the Dell Inspiron 15 7559 Notebook  [(specifications here)](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Inspiron-15-7559-Notebook-Review.154635.0.html)
According to the above website

- It has a 15.6 Inch Screen
- It has a GTX 960M GPU
- It has a Intel Core i7-6700HQ CPU [(Specs here)](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i7-6700HQ-Notebook-Processor.149420.0.html)

And the battery specs:

Idle (without WLAN, min brightness) : 11h 49min

WiFi Surfing v1.3 : 3h 52min

Load (maximum brightness) : 1h 16min

Hope that helps

Comment: This was a good while ago but better late than never. 
Ended up going with this + upgrading to 16GB ram and an M.2 SSD. it's a decent computer with a lot of bang for your buck. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try the [Razer Blade Pro 4K gaming laptop](http://toptechreview.tech/best-17-inch-laptop/) it is perfect for development. It uses the 7th generation core i7 CPU. It has 2.9GHz speed, with a 3.9GHz Turbo and 4.3GHz over-clock potential. It has Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 GPU with 8GB of VRAM.

[image]

Comment: It also appears to be, per the definition in the OP, "Incredibly expensive"

Comment: A $4000 laptop is not even close to fitting in a $800-$1000 budget.